# Как обнаружить не отображаемую кириллицу "�"

Tags: php, php7

Как можно ее идентифицировать?
Чтобы trur или false возвращала?
Хочу в цикле прописать, чтобы слово не возвращалось, если есть этот знак.
UTF-8 в header прописана.

Пробовал сделать так

```
$world_len = mb_strlen($word, "UTF-8") - 1; // $word не пуста
$word = mb_substr($word,0,$world_len,"UTF-8");
```

Итого

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen()
```

Comment: Думаю примерно как то так `if(preg_match( '/^([а-яА-ЯЁё]+)$/u', $string)) {...}`

Comment: @Spartacus preg_match не помогает